# Rename label in YiiBooster ckEditorRow

Tags: php, yii, yii-booster

How do I rename a ckEditorRow panel as highlighted below. I guess its taking the name from the passed in value (in this case 'subject').

[image]

I'm trying things like below but getting nowhere

```
$form->ckEditorRow($subject,'subject',array('options' => array('title'=>'new title')));
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by rename? Id or label? What is value of `$subject`?

Comment: I've updated my question to be more accurate. I've just tried both your suggestions in the array with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

To change label, ovverride [`attributeLabels`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#attributeLabels-detail) in your `$subject` model.

Simply return array with field name as keys and value as label, ie:

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'subject' => 'Custom Subject Label',
        ... more labels
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's helpful, but I actially want to remove the whole label on the UI (in other words rename it ''). I obviously want the label to appear elsewhere so I can't try your suggestion. Is there no way I can rename the widget?

Comment: Maybe try to set third param to `array('label' => false)`, default Yii widgets will hide label if set like that to false, but this is custom extension, so i'm not sure if it will work.